# How to pass data to a method using Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have a `Reader` class which looks like so

```
public class Reader {

    public void read(List<String> filesToRead) {
        for (String file : filesToRead) {
            System.out.println(file);
        }
    }
}
```

My `App` class is as follows

```
public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("Beans.xml");

        Reader reader = (Reader) context.getBean("reader");

        reader.read(LIST OF STRINGS TO BE PASSED HERE);
    }
}
```

My Beans.xml looks like so

```
<bean id="reader" class="com.mypackage.Reader"/>
```

I'm wondering if it is possible for me to pass a list of strings to the `read(List<String> files)` method using Spring. I'd rather do this in Spring than creating the list of strings in code as the list of strings would change in the future therefore I'd rather not modify code but just touch some Spring files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Import the spring util namespace. Then you can define a list bean as

```
<util:list id="myList" value-type="java.lang.String">
    <value>foo</value>
    <value>bar</value>
</util:list>
```

Now you can inject or Autowire this mylist to reader bean. Otherwise consider using

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.config
Class MethodInvokingFactoryBean
```

Comment: nice answer but tell me how we get list in java file

Comment: When trying to create a list bean as you have stated, I get a message in my IDE stating that "Element util:list is not allowed here".

Comment: Did you add the util namespace  xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util" and schemamlocation                         http://www.springframework.org/schema/util

Comment: I've fixed it, there was something else in my xml which was breaking things.

Comment: great , you could also accept the answer if it worked for you

Answer (score 1):

You could define a Spring bean of `java.util.ArrayList` type, like this

```
<bean id="files" class="java.util.ArrayList">
    <constructor-arg>
        <list>
            <value>fiel1</value>
            <value>fiel2</value>
            <value>fiel3</value>
        </list>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

And use that bean in the code

```
Reader reader = (Reader) context.getBean("reader");
List<String> files = (List<String>)context.getBean("files");
reader.read(files);
```